# can anyone else submit my thesis behalf of me

Tags: thesis, undergraduate, degree, research-misconduct

I did an undergraduate thesis with my partner. It don't have any missed, wrong or theft information. I was ill and long away from my dorm that time. So I told my partner to print and submit it. He had to sign my declaration page too by my name becasue I could not that time.That paper have two different name signature but by the same perosn. Is this going to be any issue for my degree ? or casue any future problem ?

Comment: You've edited this twice and removed the significant information, making the accepted answer incomprehensible.

Comment: Please don’t vandalize your post. This is already sufficiently vague that no one could figure out who you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems I see is that our friend falsified your signature and you did not say so before you friend handed in your thesis. The first should not have happened, that was wrong. You could have solved this a lot easier if you just sent an email explaining your situation before handing in the thesis. You are not the first student who got ill close to a deadline... They would probably have suggested a similar solution, without faking signatures, and it would have all been above board.

So what you did was wrong and it is possible you are in trouble. However, if they know the situation the most likely outcome will be you get privately told what I told you above and they leave it at that. If they don't know the situation, then they may suspect fraud, and you will have to explain it and hope they believe you.

Comment: Its probably in the university regulations somewhere that the declaration has to be signed by the person submitting the degree.

Comment: Ofcourse, typical sollutions for when someone is ill and cannot hand those in in person, is to allow them to preliminary submit the thesis without that form and the student can hand the form in later when (s)he is well again or to allow some form of electronic signature.

Comment: I wonder what happens if someone is too ill to do anything. Could a relative or friend hand in the thesis, of course giving all the information. At an extreme, could you wake up from a coma with a PhD?

Comment: I would expect the university to be as accommodating as possible. At the same time, having a family member who is that ill is great way of realizing how unimportant those deadlines are. So in most cases I would suspect an arrangement will be found to freeze the process till the student is well again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general answer than is probably required, but may not fit the case at hand.

It is possible and legal (some places, at least) for one person to sign for another, with permission and with a notation by the actual signer. It thus becomes possible for any authority to check on the validity, even though the signatures "don't match". Illness of one party is often a cause for such to occur. My spouse, for example, recently signed an important document on my behalf based on a verbal approval.

But that wasn't done, apparently.

My best guess, however, is that you can work it out after the fact with no consequences by appealing to "authority" whatever that is.

Given some of the now deleted details, it doesn't seem like any fraudulent intent is involved.